# Как можно при краше приложения Android вести лог?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Написал приложение под Android на C# (Visual Studio плагин **Xamarin**). Приложение обширное по функционалу, т.е. все в **try...catch** не обернешь, да и глупо это весь код в **try...catch** оборачивать. Замечено на слабых девайсах приложение частенько падает причем каждых раз в разных местах. Такой вопрос, как при краше приложения вести лог для последующего анализа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это делают подключая какую-нибудь систему сбора крашей. Xamarin нынче пропагандирует для приложений на их платформе систему [HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/), там кстати много чего ещё кроме краш репортов, аналитики всякие, системы дистрибуции, но этим всем не обязательно пользоваться тоже. На халяву там можно держать до двух приложений.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Logcat в android studio)) ну ет чисто под java, т.е. ты можешь использовать это и для xamarin.

Ну должен бить логер/дебагер под xamarin.